# How to remove "Must be behind the target." on Shred and Backstab

Tags: azerothcore

How do you remove the requirement to be behind the target for the spell Shred for druids and Backstab for Rogues. I have tested it with the stoneharry spell editor and unchecked / checked facingFront without any results. I have reviewed all 3 effects + flags in the editor and nothing points to behind the target.

Furthermore I have deleted the entry on all ranks for Shred and Backstab in table `spell_custom_attr` with attributes `131072`... but the spells Shred and Backstab still don't work when in front of the mob.

Did anyone get any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a custom attribute called `SPELL_ATTR0_CU_REQ_CASTER_BEHIND_TARGET` that is applied to the spells that require the player to be behind the target to successfully cast the spell. You can find this in [SpellMgr.cpp on line 3119-3179](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/06c458e748f88b29383971462493eb642b7c1b94/src/server/game/Spells/SpellMgr.cpp#L3119-L3179) where the spells Backstab and Shred are defined to have the flag applied.

Removing the spellid's from this switch statement should resolve your issue.